# How to debug commonjs style module of React

Tags: reactjs, browserify, babeljs

All:

I am pretty new to React work-flow. Right now, say I have a module like:

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
var Todo = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello there </div>;
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("div1"))
```

I wonder how can I use it in React project and debug it? Most posts talk about browserify and babel, could anyone show me a working example(from transpile to debug, screenshot will be much appreciated) for this simple case?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that there are three main things you need to look at.

- [Browserify](http://browserify.org/articles.html)
- [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) + [Babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify)
- [React Dev Tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools)

As a brief guide, here's what you'll need to do.

### Install Your Dependencies

If you're going to use React and ReactDOM, then you'll need to install them with NPM.

```
# ignore first step if you already have a package.json
npm init -y

npm install --save react react-dom
```

You'll also need the tools you're going to use to actually make builds.

```
npm install --save-dev browserify babelify babel-preset-react
```

This will allow you to call `require('react')` from files inside this project.

### Create a Build Script

You'll need to run a browserify command that will transpile your JSX code into plain old Javascript.

Open your `package.json` and add a new property to the scripts object.

```
{
  "build": "browserify input.js -o output.js -t [ babelify [ react ] ]"
}
```

If you also want browserify to generate sourcemaps, be use to include the debug flag `-d`.

To run this script, type `npm run build` into the command line.

The [babelify readme](https://github.com/babel/babelify) has more examples for this part of the workflow.

### Install React Dev Tools

[image]

Add the React Dev Tools extension to your browser. This gives you a live editable preview for your component tree, as well as exposing props and state too.

It makes it much easier to debug your components.

---

One final word of warning, your example contains the following code.

```
ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("div1"))
```

Unless you are sure that the DOM has loaded, a call to `getElementById` will return `null` and your application won't render.

Easily solved by placing this code within a listener.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("div1"))
});
```